# Papers publish/are published

Tags: grammar

I am reading a text and it says the following;

'Some papers publish every day, while some only publish once or twice a week.'

'Most of the papers publish in the morning, but there are also some papers which publish in the evening.'

I was wondering if it would be better to use a form of 'to be' in these sentences.

I was also wondering if you could use the word 'newspaper' as the publishing company.

Comment: _Publish_ can used [transitively or intransitively.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/publish). Also: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publish

Comment: It's a personal choice thing.

Comment: I could write an answer for you explaining who a publisher is, and what they do, but first you should look at some references and see if they don't clear up your confusion.

Comment: Our regional newspapers go by various titles but are all published by one company. So, no to the last question.

Answer (score 0):

*Papers* means *newspapers* here, and in your examples, *papers* stands for *newspaper companies*:

> *Some newspaper companies publish every day, while some only publish once or twice a week.*

You could also say:

> *Some papers are published every day, while some are only published once or twice a week.*

That uses the passive voice; *papers* now refers to the actual news publications, and the agent—the *newspaper companies*—is offstage somewhere.

I think you are trying to read your examples as agentless, so-called [middle voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labile_verb) sentences, like this one:

> *Some eggs cook fast, while others cook more slowly.*

Even though someone is cooking the eggs, it seems as if they're cooking themselves.

But while eggs cook and cakes bake and snow melts, papers don't really publish (which is how we know *papers* means *newspaper companies* in your examples).